# Positioning three buttons on the web page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three buttons on my web page. I want to put two buttons to the far right and far left corner of the web page and one in the middle. I tried this CSS, but management wants to move the buttons further right and further left:

```
.buttons-flex {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

so I changed the css to this:

```
.left-btn {
    float: left;
}

.right-btn {
    float: right;
}

.center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
   
  
}
```

with the above css, the buttons are not properly aligned and not enough space between them. Below is the screen shot of the buttons:

[image]

I want the download button right edge to be aligned with the above black color line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}

.button-left {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Container contain all the buttons,and the button-right and button-left will push the button as far as the container

Comment: Hi @Cognia, Your solution kind of works. Is it possible to give  more right margin to the .button-right . that way, it will be aligned to the above black line that I have.

Comment: You can give a button-rigth a `position:relative`,and then use left / right to adjust the position of it,try it.@Anjali

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```css
#button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="button-container">
  <button>Button1</button>
  <button>Button2</button>
  <button>Button3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I already had in my code, but the button does not move to the far right with the above code.

Comment: I see. This honestly seems like more of a css grid scenario if you want precise widths for each column. If you could provide a crude mockup of what the desired end product looks like I could help a little better, but it looks like Cognia's solution is almost working for you